# Producing pandas DataFrame from table in text file

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a text file which looks like this:

```
(v14).K TaskList[Parameter Estimation].(Problem)Parameter Estimation.Best Value
5.00885e-007    3.0914e+007
5.75366e-007    2.99467e+007
6.60922e-007    2.99199e+007
```

I'm trying to get this data into a pandas dataframe. The code I've written below partially works but has formatting issues:

```
def parse_PE_results(results_file):
    with open(results_file) as f:
        data=f.readlines()
    parameter_value=[]
    best_value=[]
    for i in data:
        split= i.split('\t')
        parameter_value.append(split[0])
        best_value.append(split[1].rstrip())
    pv=pandas.Series(parameter_value,name=parameter_value[0])
    bv=pandas.Series(best_value,name=best_value[0])
    df=pandas.DataFrame({parameter_value[0]:pv,best_value[0]:bv})
    return df
```

I get the feeling that there must be an easier, more 'pythonic' way of building a data frame from text files. Would anybody happen to know what that is?

Comment: Why don't you use pd.read_csv??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). The entire `parse_PE_results` function can be replaced with

```
df = pd.read_csv(results_file, delimiter='\t')
```

You'll also enjoy better performance by using `read_csv` instead of calling
`data=f.readlines()` and looping through it line by line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - knew there must have been an easier way. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately this code produces rounding errors in this particular situation - since I'm working with high precision numbers very close to 0. Do you know a way to use `pd.read_csv` with more decimal points? I've tried using `dtype=numpy.float64` as an argument to `read_csv` but this didn't work

Comment: You could use `dtype=np.float128` to store the floats with more precision. If that does not help, please elaborate on the oft-used but unenlightening phrase "it didn't work". Can you modify the example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Hi Unutbu. It turns out that the code actually did what I wanted but didn't print all digits to screen. Thank for the help.

Comment: Ah, in that case you could use `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.20f}'.format` to have DataFrames display more decimal digits. (Change the number in `.20f` to control the number of digits.)